# How i can calculate a function across all columns with one column but all the other column that have no NA and no 0, using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

i have a data frame that looks like this :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2.1 | 6.2 |
| 2 | 3.2 | 3.2 | 0 |
| 3 | 4.4 | NA | 8.3 |
| 4 | NA | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | NA | NA | 8.8 |
| 6 | NA | NA | 0 |
| 7 | 30 | 0 | 9.1 |
| 8 | 30 | 6.6 | 0 |

I want to calculate the pariwise sum of A with all the columns (including itself) but only those who match the A but are NOT NA and NOT 0.

The ideal output must be :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72 | 12.6 | 22.9 | 68.4 |

```
library(tidyverse)
A = seq(1:8)
B = c(0,3.2,4.4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
C = c(2.1,3.2,NA,0,NA,NA,0,6.6)
D = c(6.2,0,8.3,0,8.8,0,9.1,0)
table = tibble(A,B,C,D);table
```

My effort is :

```
table%>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(A))%>%
  dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x,A),na.rm=TRUE))
```

How i can do this in R using dplyr ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `base`

```r
sapply(table, \(x) sum((x + table$A)[!is.na(x) & x != 0]))
```

2. `dplyr`

```r
table %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum((.x + A)[!is.na(.x) & .x != 0])))

# # A tibble: 1 × 4
#       A     B     C     D
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    72  12.6  22.9  48.4
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.If instead of the sum function i wanted to implement the correlation function that changes must be made ?

Comment: how/where did you learn that `\(x)` is equivalent to `function(x)`. this is a very neat trick and where there is one there are (usually) others!

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson You could convert 0 to `NA` if necessary and then use somthing like `sapply(table, \(x) cor(x, table$A, use = 'complete.obs'))` or `cor(table, use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')[1, ]`